# Can Selenium and Bromine 3 execute overnight and email the results

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-rc

I would like to automate the testing with selenium - even when I am right now a beginner with automatic testing and especially selenium. Therefor I am working with Bromine 3 RC 2.

> Is there a way to test an web application each night and send an email with the status of the test? Would you use another tool instead of Bromine 3? What tools do you use in combination with Selenium?

Answer (score 3):

Bromine is more of test management tool and you could definitely live with out. Though having test management tool has its own advantages.

Besides Bromine you could also use - TestLink and [XStudio](http://www.xqual.com/). XStudio has facility to execute Selenium test, though I am not sure of TestLink

Testing app build each night and sending mail notification can be achieved using Continuous Build Integration tools aka CI tools. You may like to have a look at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) for this

Answer (score 3):

I only did a few learning lessons myself with Selenium (I am not a developer). But I enjoyed working with the book "[Selenium Simplified](http://www.compendiumdev.co.uk/selenium/)". It uses ECLIPSE IDE, JAVA and Selenium.

For Email Notification I found an interesing snippet [here](http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/2011/01/selenium-send-email-notifications.html): "How to initiate .vbs file from Java"

Hope it might give you some starting points.

edit: first link fixed

Comment: +1 for Selenium Simplified. It will also show you how to set up Hudson to run your tests nightly.

Answer (score 3):

I use Jenkins (formerly Hudson). You can set it to run your tests on a schedule, and email the results. The actual tests are python/selenium with nosetests --with-xunit driving. I use environment variables to select platform and browser, this is all configured in the Jenkins job.

Answer (score 3):

I use a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) build on [Hudson CI](http://hudson.java.net/) there's a good Selenium [Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/) that will do most of the work

Answer (score 1):

I used [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration to automate Selenium testing.

1. Set up automated tests with selenium, save in nunit c# class library (can also work for any other unit testing framework that works with TeamCity). Save the library in SVN.
2. Set up config in TeamCity to build and run unit tests on a fixed schedule (mine run at 3am).
3. On the machine that hosts TeamCity, set up the Selenium server to run in the background [as a Windows Service](http://unintelligible.org/blog/2009/07/28/installing-selenium-rc-as-a-windows-service/).

The TeamCity configuration can be modified to automatically send emails at the conclusion of each successful build, only on failed tests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As for now (while this stackexchange site is still in private beta) I would suggest to look for answers on [answers tagged selenium on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium)